# jQuery has stopped recognizing click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function that is called every time a user goes through a new step to bind the click event to each new item that is added to the page, and it was working fine but now it's stopped and I cannot figure out why

Below is the function ([or click here for full js](http://pastebin.com/6N3cgnCE)):

```
function bindClickEvents() {
    console.log('bindClickEvents');

    $(".wall-dropdown .item").unbind('click').on('click', function() {

        console.log('Item clicked');

        if ($(this).hasClass('range')) {
            $(".item.range").removeClass('active');

            selectedRange = $(this).data('id');

            $(this).addClass('active');

            selectedStyle = null;
            selectedColour = null;
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('style')) {
            $(".item.style").removeClass('active');

            selectedStyle = $(this).data('id');

            $(this).addClass('active');

            selectedColour = null;
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('colour')) {
            $(".item.colour").removeClass('active');

            selectedColour = $(this).data('id');

            $(this).addClass('active');
        }

        runFilter();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `off` with `on` (not unbind)

```
 $(".wall-dropdown .item").off('click').on('click', function() {
```

However I suggest you simply switch to *delegated event handlers* (attached to a non changing ancestor element):

e.g

```
 $(document).on("click", ".wall-dropdown .item", function()
```

It works by listening for the specified event to bubble-up to the connected element, then it applies the jQuery selector. Then it applies the function *to the matching items that caused the event*.

This way the match of `.wall-dropdown .item` is only done at event time so the items can exists later than event registration time.

`document` is the best default of no other element is closer/convenient. Do not use `body` for delegated events as it has a bug (to do with styling) that can stop mouse events firing.  Basically, if styling causes a computed body height of 0, it stops receiving bubbled mouse events. Also as `document` *always* exists, you do not need to wrap document-based delegated handlers inside a DOM ready :)

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I had no idea I could even do that, learn something new everyday

Comment: They also have the added benefit of attaching faster (as it is only a single handler). Any slight delay at event time is negligible (unless you can click your mouse 50,000 times a second) :)

Comment: New problem, it seems to be repeating clicks, if you go here http://www.puretreecork.com/wall and open your console. Select 'Cork collections' dropdown and select an item, and then select it again, and again, it seems to be repeating everything, not too sure what's going on

Comment: You only register a delegated event handler *once* at *page-load* time. Make sure you reorganise your code to suit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind event to `body` like

`$('body').on('click','.wall-dropdown .item',function(){...some code...})`

to prevent reinitialization of event?
this code automaticaly works with each new element `.wall-dropdown .item`

Comment: Never use `body` for delegated event handlers. Use `document` as the default as body can stop receiving mouse events if the styling results in a computed body height of 0. See my answer for details.

Comment: thanks. supose this possible, simply i never met body with zero height, so used body

Comment: They do happen (absolutely positioned children cause it for one), so always safer to use `document`. `$(document)` is also faster than `$('body')` (about the same as `$(document.body)`), but also `document` *always* exists so you can connect delegated handlers to it outside of DOM ready :)